# How to check computer's timezone through Terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, timezone

I am writing a bash script which at some point needs to determine a user's timezone, so how exactly can I check the timezone in Terminal? I would like to be able to get output in terms of GMT and UTC. Though if I can get the output in terms of any others then a list of those and how to get them would be nice. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use:

```
timedatectl status | grep "Time zone"
```

Without the `grep` you get a lot more of information.

As pointed out by [@Christian Ulbrich](https://askubuntu.com/users/671057/christian-ulbrich) in [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767045/how-to-check-computers-timezone-through-terminal/767047?noredirect=1#comment1774029_767047) the wording for timezone seems to change depending on which version of `timaedatectl` or `systemd` you are using (on 14.04.5 it seems to be `Timezone` written in one word), so to make sure you get the proper output, you can run the above command without piping through grep to make sure you grep the right thing.

Here an example output of the above `timedatectl status` command on 18.04 without piping it through to grep:

[image]

Comment: small edit: you might want to just grep "zone", since Timezone is treated as one word sometimes

Comment: In which language this is written in one word in this case?

Comment: on Ubuntu, timedatectl show timezone as one word

Comment: Then i must be on some special Ubuntu maybe, above you can see the output of `timedatectl` without the grep on Ubuntu 18.04, and it was the same on 16.04 which I had installed the time I wrote this answer. needless to say that it was the same on 16.10, 17.04 and 17.10 before I installed bionic. Even without the status parameter `timedatect`l returns me the same output.

Comment: Ah okay, might be different package versions also. Maybe you'd be better off grepping a case insensitive "timezone" or "time zone" just to be sure.

Comment: @Videonauth On Ubuntu _14.04.5 LTS_ it is indeed `Timezone` and thus `grep "Time zone"` does not work. Looks like it is depending on the version of Systemd used.

Comment: @ChristianUlbrich Thank you. will change my answer accordingly when I am at my PC again.